# ngx-infinite-scroll with mat-option: (scrolled) procedure isn't called and nested scrollbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, infinite-scroll, legacy

I'm using angular v15 and legacy Angular Material and trying get to get ngx-infinite-scroll to work with a mat-select/mat-option.
We have been using ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll but since that currently isn't working with legacy Angular Material I have been asked to look for an alternative and found ngx-infinite-scroll. But I'm not sure if that will actually work with mat-select/mat-option so I gave it a try.

The html is below. I've seen people using either infiniteScroll or infinite-scroll in the div but it doesn't seem to make a difference which one I use.
The problem is that the scrollDown is never called.
I did notice that there are 2 scrollbars so I'm probably doing something wrong.

```
   <mat-select panelClass="lazyloadselector" 
                [formControl]="appselect" 
                [complete]="offset === tempOptions.length"
                (openedChange)="openChanged($event)" 
                [disabled]="disabled" 
                (selectionChange)="selectionChangedTrigger($event)">
  <mat-option unselectable="on" 
              [disabled]="true">
      <input  type="text" 
              (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
              placeholder="Search..." 
              #input 
              (keydown.space)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  </mat-option>
  <div class="search-results" 
       infiniteScroll 
       infinite-scroll 
       [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
       [infiniteScrollThrottle]="150" 
       (scrolled)="scrollDown()">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of tempInfiniteScrollOptions" 
                 [value]="option.value">{{option.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </div>
</mat-select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To best fit the requirements of your project, I wonder if you could use `mat-autocomplete` found [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview). In Angular, this component works very similarly to what you are trying to accomplish by throwing in an `input` with a `mat-form-field` and `mat-option` to make a searchable drop down menu. `mat-autocomplete` accepts `mat-options` and `input` but should not use a `mat-select` within it. Essentially, `mat-autocomplete` would take the place of `mat-select` entirely and become the container of the drop down menu.

Consider the following structure for your approach:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input>
    <mat-autocomplete>
       <div infinite-scroll ...>
           <div or ng-container *ngFor...>
               <mat-option>
```

You are likely getting a double scroll bar because both `mat-select` and `infinite-scroll` provide a scroll. Hope this helps!